# Which type of compression performs better?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7

I am currently working on an app that uses Gzip encoder it works pretty well but what i want to know is if i remove the gzip encoder will the standard IIS 7 compression work any faster than the Gzip encoder?

the compression is currently done on the client side and the webservice

thanks

Comment: at what point are you doing the gzip encoding... are we talking about web based compression or are you compression a file to be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one good article on IIS7 compression which tells about its performance

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx

secondly on msdn it is written that "Compression of dynamic application responses can affect CPU resources because IIS does not cache compressed versions of dynamic output. "

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003(WS.10).aspx

Please check these factors and compare your cpu usage when you are using gzip compression and iis7 compression